# Setting up ninject comparison rules I+"Somevalue" = Somevalue

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

Hello my question might be a little bit stupid, but I will be very gratitude if someone will help me with it.

So my question is: how to set automatic class to interface comparison with rule `I+"Class" = "Class"` using ninject?

Let us imagine that we have a lot of classes class in one project and it's interfaces.

```
Class class1 : Iclass1{..}
Class class2 : Iclass2{..}
Class class3 : Iclass3{..}
```

and so-so-so... with a hundred of classes and it's interfaces.

Writing for each class binding rule is a quite anoying, I know there should be an automatic way to bind it like in Castle Windsor.

Thx, a lot. I'm quite new in Ninject.

Special thx if someone will provide an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to map with the rule:

```
I+“Somevalue” = Somevalue
```

Instead, you can use reflection to find interface of each class, the code below assume all types is in executing assembly and your classes' name begin with "Class", the approach is pretty like:

```
var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                     .Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith("Class"));

foreach (var type in types)
{
    var interfaceType = type.GetInterfaces()
                            .Single();

    kernel.Bind(type).To(interfaceType);
}
```

But easily, you can change the way to filter your type based on your convention.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki) - it has a default binder that binds all `IFoo`s to `Foo`s, and of course you can define much stronger conventions.

Simple example:

```
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions;

namespace NinjectConventionsDemo
{
    public interface ITool { }
    public class Tool : ITool { }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind(convention => convention
                                          .FromThisAssembly()
                                          .SelectAllClasses()
                                          .BindAllInterfaces()
                );
            var tool = kernel.Get<ITool>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Maris - well, it's an example. But the extension should do exactly what you're looking for. Are all of your classes `internal`, like in the above example? That can explain why it isn't working.